# How to detect file redirection to the Windows VirtualStore?

Tags: c#, virtualization, uac, virtualstore

Since the release of Win Vista, Microsoft introduced file virtualization for legacy applications running as 32bit processes. Released as part of Microsoft's User Account Control (UAC) any legacy applications attempting to write to any locations considered protected by the operating system are redirected to the VirtualStore.

At this point, steps have been taken to ensure that the application in question now runs as a 64bit process that is UAC aware, however, this does little to address the issue of migrating the users data to a location that is considered safe from virtualization.

While troubleshooting this issue, I've found that when dealing with multiple user accounts some changes have been made within the legacy path located at `C:\Program Files(x86)\MyApp\Data` while at the same time, changes have been made to the VirtualStore located at `%localappdata%\VirtualStore\Programs\MyApp\Data`. The question being, how can I detect if any file/folder virtualization is taking place and how can I merge the two locations?

**EDIT:** I found several websites that detail the problem and how to duplicate it, but nothing that includes a way to fix it. I did find this reference [FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332330%28VS.85%29.aspx) that defines a file attribute that seems promising - I found another reference somewhere, though I can't remember where, that states that this is the attribute used by Windows to indicate that file virtualization is taking place and flags the request for redirection.

These links describe the issue:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/GemingLeader/windows-file-and-registry-virtualization/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66275/Windows-Vista-File-and-Registry-Virtualization

[http://download.microsoftvirtuallabs.com/download/8/a/7/8a71365b-4c80-4e60-8185-8f12f59bf1d4/UACDataRedirection.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20091229140330/http://download.microsoftvirtuallabs.com/download/8/a/7/8a71365b-4c80-4e60-8185-8f12f59bf1d4/UACDataRedirection.pdf)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wasn't easy, but I found how to detect whether UAC virtualization is enabled. Calling [`GetTokenInformation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and passing in `TokenVirtualizationEnabled` as the information class will return whether file and registry virtualization is enabled. Here is a C function to do it:

```
// Gets whether the current process has UAC virtualization enabled.
// Returns TRUE on success and FALSE on failure.
BOOL GetVirtualizationEnabled(BOOL *enabled) {
    HANDLE token;
    DWORD tmpEnabled;
    DWORD returnLen;
    BOOL retVal = TRUE;

    if(!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &token))
        return FALSE;

    if(!GetTokenInformation(token, TokenVirtualizationEnabled,
            &tmpEnabled, sizeof(tmpEnabled), &returnLen)) {
        retVal = FALSE;
        goto err;
    }

    *enabled = tmpEnabled;

err:
    CloseHandle(token);

    return retVal;
}
```

A bit harder with P/Invoke, but here it is, including the P/Invoke headers:

```
enum TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS
{
    TokenUser = 1,
    TokenGroups,
    TokenPrivileges,
    TokenOwner,
    TokenPrimaryGroup,
    TokenDefaultDacl,
    TokenSource,
    TokenType,
    TokenImpersonationLevel,
    TokenStatistics,
    TokenRestrictedSids,
    TokenSessionId,
    TokenGroupsAndPrivileges,
    TokenSessionReference,
    TokenSandBoxInert,
    TokenAuditPolicy,
    TokenOrigin,
    TokenElevationType,
    TokenLinkedToken,
    TokenElevation,
    TokenHasRestrictions,
    TokenAccessInformation,
    TokenVirtualizationAllowed,
    TokenVirtualizationEnabled,
    TokenIntegrityLevel,
    TokenUIAccess,
    TokenMandatoryPolicy,
    TokenLogonSid,
    MaxTokenInfoClass
}

public const UInt32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;
public const UInt32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = 0x00020000;
public const UInt32 TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
public const UInt32 TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
public const UInt32 TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004;
public const UInt32 TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
public const UInt32 TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010;
public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020;
public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040;
public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080;
public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100;
public const UInt32 TOKEN_READ = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | TOKEN_QUERY);
public const UInt32 TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY |
    TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE |
    TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS | TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT |
    TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool GetTokenInformation(
    IntPtr TokenHandle,
    TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS TokenInformationClass,
    IntPtr TokenInformation,
    int TokenInformationLength,
    out uint ReturnLength);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetTokenInformation(IntPtr TokenHandle, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS TokenInformationClass,
    ref uint TokenInformation, uint TokenInformationLength);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle,
    uint DesiredAccess, out IntPtr TokenHandle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

static bool TryGetVirtualizationEnabled(out bool enabled) {
    IntPtr processHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
    IntPtr token;
    uint returnLen;
    object tmpEnabled = new uint();

    enabled = false;
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(tmpEnabled, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    try {
        if(!OpenProcessToken(processHandle, TOKEN_QUERY, out token))
            return false;

        try {
            if(!GetTokenInformation(token, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenVirtualizationEnabled,
                                    handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(uint)), out returnLen))
                return false;

            enabled = (uint)tmpEnabled != 0;
        } finally {
            CloseHandle(token);
        }
    } finally {
        handle.Free();
    }

    return true;
}
```

I tried turning UAC virtualization on and off with Task Manager and verified that the correct result is returned. Enabling and disabling virtualization can be done by calling [`SetTokenInformation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Microsoft says they plan on removing UAC virtualization in a future Windows version and for programs to not rely on it existing. I saw a suggestion by someone to make a separate program that is not UAC aware to move files from the VirtualStore to AppData, but I don't know if that's a good solution or not.

Comment: Does this method detect if Virtualization in enabled in general or if it is enabled for a specific file/folder?

Comment: In general. If virtualization is enabled on a process, all writes from that process to the Program Files folder, the Windows folder, and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE in the registry are redirected (and a couple others). It can't be enabled for some of these folders and not others.

Comment: Rereading your initial question, it sounds like you don't want to detect whether virtualization is taking place. If you are running a 64-bit process that is UAC aware, then you know virtualization is disabled. To access data put in the VirtualStore by an old version of the program (that had virtualization enabled), the program can look in %LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore to see if there is any of its data in there. If there is, it can move the data to the correct place, merging it if needed.

Comment: This is only partly true... while troubleshooting the issue of UAC Virtualization I found that, even though the application process functions just fine with the required manifest (being UAC aware), any changes made over the Windows File Shares via SMB often redirected to the VirtualStore do to the fact that SMB is nearly always treated as a limited system process.

Comment: I had hoped to be able to determine if redirection was actively taking place so I could inform the user of the danger - encouraging them to move their data to a more ideal location. The problem with Virtualization is that its on a per-user bases meaning that the virtualized data could be spread out among multiple user accounts; which in its self is a problem. What I really need is a way to determine if this redirection has taken place and ideally merge the two data sets.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, here is a version of the detection code in Delphi:

```
unit checkvirtual;

interface
uses windows;

function GetVirtualizationEnabled(var enabled:Boolean):Boolean;

implementation

// Gets whether the current process has UAC virtualization enabled.
// Returns TRUE on success and FALSE on failure.
function GetVirtualizationEnabled(var enabled:Boolean):Boolean;
var
  token:THandle;
  tmpEnabled:DWORD;
  returnLen:DWORD;
begin
  result:=false;
  enabled:=false;
  if not(OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, token)) then exit;
  try
    if not(GetTokenInformation(token, TokenVirtualizationEnabled,
              @tmpEnabled, sizeof(tmpEnabled), returnLen)) then exit;

    enabled:=tmpEnabled<>0;
    result:=true;
  finally
    CloseHandle(token);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to flag if you are "running" from the local app data path, in which case:

```
var currentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);  
var appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
Console.WriteLine(
    "Current path is:{0}, AppData Path is {1}, Current is subpath of appdata path:{2}",
    currentPath, 
    appDataPath, 
    currentPath.StartsWith(appDataPath)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm looking for a solution to not just be UAC aware but to actively detect whether file redirection or virtualization is taking place. If possible, I'd like to be able to detect this weather the process is currently running or not - since this is a network based application. At this point, I've been unable  to find any methods of identifying whether file redirection to the VirtualStore is or has ever taken place; short of search through each users profile for the VirtualStore data/files, I can think of no other way of identifying the VirtualStore data.

Comment: @Simpleton Ah, I see - sorry, I'm not intimately aware with the VirtualStore details enough to give that particular answer; this blurb would just let you know once the app has started up.