# cant see git folders in windows even though Ive it set to show hidden files

Tags: git, windows-explorer

I've cloned a repository using the windows command prompt, but the only reason I know it exists and cloned succesfully is that I can see it with git bash.

In both the command prompt and in windows explorer, it is hidden.

I have went to the Folder and Search options and I had it already set to show hidden files, so Im out of ideas to why they dont appear there.

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious... Are you sure you're looking at the same path in Git Bash and Windows Explorer? Are you not in two different folders that happen to have the same name?

Comment: yep, to be more specific I created folder in c:windows called "gitwork" just for this and yes when I go to the "gitwork" folder and run `ls` in git bash I see the folders, yet in windows explorer i dont. Im starting to wonder has it something to do with the windows folder

Comment: ok, i was right, i tested it outside of the windows folder and it worked

Comment: yes its solved, ive answered but wait to accept, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also wanted to understand why sometime I could find my .git repo folder in Windows 7 file explorer on some but not other repos. I found it to be Windows Virtual Store was being implemented whenever my git repo was in what was a protected area, say working on a plugin for an application in C:\Program Files. Here is another question asking how to find such re-directed files.

[How to detect file redirection to the Windows VirtualStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005081/how-to-detect-file-redirection-to-the-windows-virtualstore)

It seems git-bash, git-gui is automatically picking up these Virtual Store files, while file-explorer doesn't. Anyway the .git folder for Virtual Store is located:

%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\

Under an identical folder structure as from the root folder to your git repo instance.

Comment: Thanks, this is a better answer than my own

Answer (score 1):

This worked outside of the C:Windows folder, I can only assume it is a setting in Windows that hides folders (Even when set to show hidden files and folders).