# Why doesn't open/write/close on a file whose path is "C:/filename" return failure in W7?

Tags: c, winapi

I have a win32 program that I've supported for years.  I just noticed that on W7 if it attempts to open/write/close a file directly in C:/, the system calls do not complain but the file is not created.  I'm sure this has something to do with W7 security, but shouldn't the system calls return -1 to let the program know its not gonna work?
It gets worse... After I realized that the system calls were not failing I figured I'd test for the presence of the file after the close() but that even succeeded!  The file does not show up in explorer, but stat(c:/filename) says its there.
This path is set by the program user, so how can I detect that the file operation is not successful if every system call I try tells me it was successful?

Comment: I think you'll find the system calls do complain. Default permissions these days are to deny file creation in the system root. Check your return values and error codes properly.

Comment: If you want the calls to fail, I believe you need to give the program a manifest asserting that it is Windows Vista compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accesses got redirected to a private folder by [UAC data redirection](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/C/D/8CD015BB-081B-49C5-A506-9C9B570B8DD2/UACDataRedirection.pptx).

That is a compatibility feature, giving programs pretend write access to the `Windows` directory and the system drive root, without compromising the system.

Comment: According to the presentation I linked, it does -- and that would make sense, as a lot of broken applications use the system root folder to avoid parsing the space in `Program Files`.

Comment: For both C:\ and C:\windows, the same thing occurs: open/write/close/stat all succeed normally even though the file isn't created there.  I found (since posting this) that access() (used instead of stat()) will tell me that the file is not there.

Comment: This question seems to discuss the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005081/how-to-detect-file-redirection-to-the-windows-virtualstore